# check on login where its admin or user

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create separate registration form for admin and user and create one table for both admin and user..my `u_admin` table has a column `admin_flag`, so when the admin is registered I send `admin_flag=1` and when user is register I send `admin_flag=0`.

Now the problem is that on my login page when the user enter his email and password the codecheck in the database that admin_flag is 0 or 1, if it is 0 the browser redirect to `user_view.php` and if admin_flag is 1 it will redirect to `admin_view.php`

please help me out...

Model

```
public function validate_user($data){

        $condition = "email =" . "'" . $data['email'] . "'" . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'AND " . "admin_flag =" . "'" . $data['admin_flag'] . "'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('admin');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function read_user_information($sess_array) {

        $condition = "email =" . "'" . $sess_array['email'] . "'AND " . "admin_flag =" . "'" . $data['admin_flag'] . "'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('admin');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
//--------login---------
    }
```

Controller

```
function login_user() {

{
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login');
        } else {
            $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );
            $result = $this->admin_model->validate_user($data);
            if($result == TRUE){
                    $sess_array = array(
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email')
                );
                // Add user data in session
                    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
                    $result = $this->admin_model->read_user_information($sess_array);
                if($result != false){



                $data = array(
                        'fname' =>$result[0]->fname,
                        // 'user_name' =>$result[0]->user_name,
                        'email' =>$result[0]->email,
                        'password' =>$result[0]->password,
                        'admin_flag'=>$result[0]->admin_flag
                    );
                        //if(num_rows()->admin_flag == 1){
                        $this->load->view('success',$data);
                    //  }
                    //  else{
                        //  $this->load->view('success2',$data);
                        //}


                }
            }
            else
                {
                    $data = array(
                        'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
                    );
                        $this->load->view('login', $data);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there is any field in your database to check it is admin or normal user??

Comment: Pass email and password to your validate_user() and get data if condition is  matched and check admin_flag value in your controller if it is 1 then redirect to admin_view.php else user_view.php

Comment: @saty yeah i create a column admin_flag...if colummn value is 1 its admin if 0 its user

Answer (score 0):

Call separate view based on the admin_flg value.

if(admin_flg == 1)

call admin view

else

call user view

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in this way:

```
if($result[0]->admin_flag== 1){
    $this->load->view('admin',$data);
}
else{
    $this->load->view('user',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Condition line:

```
$condition = "email =" . "'" . $data['email'] . "'" . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'AND " . "admin_flag =" . "'" . $data['admin_flag'] . "'";
```

In $data variable you need to pass 'admin_flag' along with email and password fields.

Change the following code in your controller file:

```
$data = array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'admin_flag' => $this->input->post('admin_flag')
        );
```